# vue 3 with swipperjs: class binding is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I'm using Vue 3 wih swiperjs.

I have issue. `v-bind:class` is acting weird here.

when I go to second slide, the `!h-auto` class is not applied to the second slide. but when I go to first slide, it's applied to the second slide while it should be applied when I'm on the second slide since the second element next to the image in the second slide is taller than the image.

the expected result is the `!h-auto` class is applied when the second element next to the image in the slide is taller than the image. it's 'in-sync' with the `v-bind:class="{ '!h-auto': isDescriptionTaller(index) }"` in other words

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cartwright-qxecew?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

I already provided the codesandbox. hope anyone can (fork and) solve the codesandbox once and for all and share it here

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is a fun one.

You set the class depending on the output of `isDescriptionTaller(index)`:

```html
<div
  :class="{ '!h-auto': isDescriptionTaller(index) }"
  :id="`image-event-${index}`"
>
```

and the function compares the height of this div with the height of the second column, and if the second column is taller, then the class will be set in order to stretch the column.

The problem now is that when the class is active, both columns share the same height, so `isDescriptionTaller(index)` will be false and the class will be removed. At which point, the second column is taller than the first, so the class will be applied again, and we are back at the beginning. Rinse and repeat. So the class basically switches itself off, which triggers it to be switched on again.

The condition is evaluated every time the slide changes, and since it is the second page, it will be called when the class is off. You can actually see the column changing height when switching slides.

To fix it, you can simply change the condition in `isDescriptionTaller(index)` from greater than to greater equal:

```
const isDescriptionTaller = (index) => {
  ...
  return description?.clientHeight >= image?.clientHeight ?? false;
};
```

Now the class is not removed when the columns share the same height, i.e. when the class is set.

---

You might want to check if it is even necessary to remove the class. If the image is taller, it shouldn't do anything, so I think you could just leave it in.

---

But if you really only want to apply the class when the image is smaller than the text, check for image [`naturalHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight) instead of column height:

```
const isDescriptionTaller = (index) => {
  const description = document.querySelector(`#description-event-${index}`);
  const image = document.querySelector(`#image-event-${index} img`); // <--- target the image

  return description?.clientHeight >= image?.naturalHeight ?? false; // <--- use image height
};
```

---

In every case, keep in mind that the image's dimensions will be 0 until the src is loaded. I think at the moment, you are using the same image on both slides, so you only run into the problem the first time the app loads (after that, the image is served from cache). Either you have to work with the `onload` event, or find a CSS solution that does not rely on calculations in JS. But one way or another, that's a different question.

Comment: tried this and not working. now the !h-auto class is also applied on the first slide as well which is not it's expected. btw, would you elaborate by "move the page to an odd slide number." ?

Comment: Oh, that was just a joke, I'll remove it. It would work, because due to the on-off cycle, the class is set at index 0,2,4, ... and it is unset at index 1,3,5,... So if it was the first or third page (index 0 or 2), the class would be on. But that's obviously not how you want to handle it.

Comment: as you said, "on-off cycle" is the best word to describe it now which actually not what I want. I think how's it supposed to work is the v-for will calculate the second element with the image container element on all slides. I don't know what's the best word to describe it

Comment: What is the problem when the class is set on the first slide? It means both columns share the same height, so the class has no effect, doesn't it? Anyway, I think I have a solution, check the updated answer.

Comment: gonna try your updated post. thanks so far anyway